# How can I read intelisense content from C#?

Tags: c#, intellisense

I'm using Nunit in C# in visual studio 2015 for testing and I need to make some reports out of it. 
Im currently getting the standards XML results and that's good, but I'd like to include my `<sumary>` information for description of the test. is that possible?

If that's not possible out of the box.. is there a way to extract this info somehow? I'm Ok doing it from another project loading the files and extracting it or something.. I really don't know how to tackle the issue

Comment: if you tell msbuild to generate the documentat and it will leave you the xml comments in an xml file

Comment: how do I tell him ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115877/how-to-generate-xml-documentation-for-csproj-with-multiple-targets