# c# - module documentation - XML documentation file

Tags: c#, xml, module, documentation

I am studying C# in my HDN school with Visual Studio.
In Windows there is a way to generate automaticaly the technical documentation from modules by going through Project > Properties and by clicking on "XML documentation file".

On Visual Studio for Mac I do not see this functionality.

May someone help me ? Does it exist or should I write manually the /// up to the module ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also add a configuration to the .csproj so the documentation file gets generated with each build. Follow this SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118584/4122889

Add this code to you .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or create a `Directory.Build.Props` file in the root of your repo and add this:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

More info on Directory.Build.Props (or .Targets):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019

Comment: @MathieuSeligmann if this satisfies your answer please mark it as so -  and if you're specifcially looking for where the option is gone on visualstudio/mac i suggest highlighting that more in the question or asking this on the microsoft forums. They're also active on stackoverflow btw, mostly monitoring the Visual studio tag.