# Specify deployment path for XML documentation output path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm using the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package for my .NET Core web api project. I want to add XML comments support so I have to set Build => Output => XML documentation file to `true` in the application settings.

[image]

Unfortunately the autogenerated path is absolute

`C:\Users\myUser\...\repository\solution\project\project.xml`

So this only works on my machine. Is there a way to use placeholders? E.g.

`{{pathToProject}}\project.xml`

so it works while debugging locally and for the deployment?

Answer (score 10):

There's an easy way to generate an XML documentation file at a relative path. Just set the `DocumentationFile` property to `true`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This was documented in another StackOverflow answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118584/19112

You can then set your `SwaggerGenOptions` to consume your XML documentation like this:

```
// Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

As shown in the sample here:
https://code-maze.com/swagger-ui-asp-net-core-web-api/#ExtendingDocumentation

Answer (score 8):

Click the `Browse...` button and select a folder under the project path, such as `bin\debug`.

Then check the `XML documentation file`. It will generate a relative path.

[image]

Comment: does this path work for every scenario? e.g. publishing, deployment, ...

Comment: to make it work I would have to set this output path "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\" so I'm not sure if this covers all the things

Answer (score 1):

You can change project.csproj then you get the xml file at debug[**desired location**] folder with a custom name.**I commented out the default line**.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <!--<DocumentationFile>C:\Users\furkan.katman\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.xml</DocumentationFile>-->
      <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\ProjectName.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my investigation went, I noticed differences between `$(ProjectDir)`, `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` or `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` in the `<DocumentationFile>` element.

In the context of my solution (.NET Core 3.1), the first two both resolved to `C:\` hence failing the build with a "Could not write to output file -- Access is denied" exception. Only the third keyword actually resolved to the folder path where my .csproj was located.

So I would suggest trying with `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` if your build fails.